# How do I fix this discord ban bot using python

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a discord bot that bans a user when I say .ban @Example_User, but when I run the code no errors pop up but then when I try to use the error appears, I've been using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THj99FuPJmI, and here is my code and error below:

```
   import discord 
   import random 
   import os
   from discord.ext import commands

   client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

   @client.event
   async def on_ready():
     print("Bot is ready")

   @client.command() 
   async def kick(ctx, member : discord.member, * , reason=None): 
     await member.kick(reason=reason)

   @client.command()
   async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
     await member.ban(reason=reason)

   client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

and here is my error[image: Error Code]

Comment: The bot needs to have Admin rights. Are you sure it has?

Comment: It does have admin rights

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457960

Comment: @Shadowcoder will do, Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord - How to give my bot permissions. \[Javascript\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224362/discord-how-to-give-my-bot-permissions-javascript)